# Where is the save data?

Tags: ultimate-chicken-horse

I'm having some steam sync problems, and I wanted to investigate manually moving my save data. I can't find it on either my OSX computer nor my Windows computer. Where is the save data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the save file is called saveData.uch, and you can find by going through this:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Ultimate Chicken Horse\UltimateChickenHorse_Data

You'll find the "saveData.uch" file in this directory.

Answer (score 1):

The save file is in the game data folder (UltimateChickenHorse_Data), the filename is "saveData.uch".

Comment: So then my question becomes: where is _that_ folder?

Comment: The game has no discrete save game folder. You can find the game folder in _WhateverDriveYouChose\Steam\steamapps\common_.

Answer (score 1):

For the Steam version on macOS, your save data is within this folder:

`~/Library/Application Support/unity.Clever Endeavour Games.Ultimate Chicken Horse/`

You can jump directly to that folder in the Finder by choosing the menu item Go > Go to Folder… (⇧⌘G) and pasting that path.

That folder contains multiple files that represent your save data. In addition to `saveData.uch`, there is the `snapshots` folder, which contains your saved levels, and the `rules` folder, which contains your saved rule sets. If you want to back up your game, it would be easiest to just back up the whole `unity.Clever Endeavour Games.Ultimate Chicken Horse` folder.

For completeness, I’ll mention another game-related path you might need to access sometimes: `~/Library/Logs/Unity/Player.log`, which contains logs from your last game session. You’ll need that file if you send any bug reports to the developers.